# Writing and Reading Files in java gives unexpected results

Tags: java, apache-commons

Please i Have a problem with the following code

```
public String encrypt(String fileToEncrypt) throws Exception{
    _cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _keyPair.getPublic());
    File inputfile = new File(fileToEncrypt);
    File outputfile = new File("C:/SECUREFILE".concat("/").concat(FilenameUtils.getName(fileToEncrypt)));
    FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile, false);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, _cipher);
    IOUtils.copy(inputstream, cos);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputstream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(cos);
    return outputfile.getPath();
}
```

The problem is that the resulting file written to disk is always 0kb. Please what am i doing wrong

Comment: Did you miss flush() and close() for the output streams?

Comment: copy is supposed to do a flush. close() wouldn't hurt, although the OS is supposed to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputstream), and IOUtils.closeQuietly(cos); to close the streams, it should work
The following piece of code works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    encrypt(new Scanner(System.in).next());
}
public static String encrypt(String fileToEncrypt) throws Exception{
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kgen.init(128);
    SecretKey _keyPair = kgen.generateKey();

    Cipher _cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    _cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _keyPair);

    File inputfile = new File(fileToEncrypt);
    File outputfile = new File("D:/SECUREFILE".concat("/").concat(FilenameUtils.getName(fileToEncrypt)));
    FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile, false);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, _cipher);
    IOUtils.copy(inputstream, cos);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputstream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(cos);
    return outputfile.getPath();
}
```

input file content : dfsdafdsfasdfsadfs

output file content : –X‰8q'4ÆZ€’®!‡tÈérë/Å±¤®v´rË

Comment: Tried that it did not work. All files written to disk are still 0KB in size

Comment: @PeterEdike can you add the piece of code where cipher is instantiated and configured. Also the keypair